# Binomial limit evaluation

Tags: limits, binomial-coefficients

I'd like to evaluate a somewhat atypical limit: for any constant $0<c<1$ and for $n$ odd, I'd like to evaluate the limit

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum\limits_{k = \frac{n+1}{2}}^n \binom{n}{k}(1 - c^n)^k(1+c^n)^{n-k}.$$
Of course, when $c=0$ this is $1/2$, but I'm most curious about the case where $c$ is near $1$.  Is there any choice of $c$ that makes this limit zero?  If someone has a nice way of thinking about the asymptotics of this in terms of $n$, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $c$ with $|c|<1$, I think the usual gaussian approximation to the binomial distribution will yield the limit $1/2$ as $n\to\infty$.
The binomial distribution in question is $X_n\sim B(n,(1-c^n)/2)$, for which the limit under study is $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_n>n/2)$.  The proposal is to pretend $X_n=n(1-c^n)/2 + \sqrt{n(1-c^{2n})/4}\, Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is standard normal.  Then the event $[X_n>n/2]$ is replaced by the event $[Z>z_n]$, where $z_n=\sqrt n c^n/\sqrt{1-c^{2n}}$.  Since $|c|<1$, we have $z_n\to0$ and $P(Z_n>z_n)\to 1/2$.  The error introduced by our pretense is bounded by the [Berry Esseen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem):
$$ \big| P(X_n>n/2) - P(Z>z_n)\big| = \mathcal O\big( \frac 1 {\sqrt n}\big),$$
where the implied constants hold uniformly in $n$ as the absolute third moments of the underlying Bernoulli rvs are uniformly bounded in $n$.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This helps in a small computation I was doing.